# Error: Cannot find module 'less' with pnpm

Tags: npm, gulp-less

Im trying to use pnpm but get this error on the buildmachine:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'less'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
        at Function.require.resolve (internal/module.js:23:19)
        at resolve_engine_path (C:\BuildAgent\_work\Web\App\node_modules\.registry.npmjs.org\accord\0.26.4\node_modules\accord\lib\index.js:65:18) at Object.exports.load (C:\BuildAgent\_work\Web\App\node_modules\.registry.npmjs.org\accord\0.26.4\node_modules\accord\lib\index.js:25:19) at Object.<anonymous> (C:\BuildAgent\_work\Web\App\node_modules\.registry.npmjs.org\gulp-less\3.3.0\node_modules\gulp-less\index.js:9:29) at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
            at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
            ##[error]Running build failed.
            ##[error]Error:
            ##[error]System.Exception: Failed to run gulp build-release
```

Im trying to reslove this error but cant figure out how to get pnpm to install the module. Accorging to this issue this should be resloved already:
https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/118

Some of the package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "aurelia-bundler": "^0.3.2",
    "aurelia-tools": "^0.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^4.1.6",
    "del": "^1.1.0",
    "eslint": "^1.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-aurelia": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.10",
    "gulp-babel": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp-bump": "^0.1.11",
    "gulp-changed": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.1.7",
    "gulp-eslint": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.9.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-plumber": "^0.6.6",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.1.0",
```

Anyone had this issue and solved it?
Please let me know if im missing some info out!

Comment: Added "less": "^2.1.1" at top-level dep in package.json and that fixed the issue

Comment: Was this issue solved? I can look into it

Comment: `pnpm install --shamefully-hoist` this worked for me. https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/1262

Answer (score -3):

You can run `npm install less` in terminal

Comment: Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.